# If a commutator has an eigenvalue $0$, do the two operators share an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A,B$ be two diagonalizable linear operators, such that their commutator $\left[A,B\right] = AB-BA$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$. Does this mean $A$ and $B$ share an eigenvector?

Of course, the vice-versa is correct. If they do share an eigenvector, the commutator necessarily has an eigenvalue of $0$. I'm not sure though if this is a sufficient condition, or only a necessary one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly we can pick a basis so that one of the operators is diagonal already. Here's a small counterexample of this sort:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mu \end{pmatrix}  \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
The eigenvalues of $B$ are $\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $0$, and all eigenvectors are of the form $(1,a,\pm 1)$, none of which live in one of the eigenspaces of $A$. But $AB-BA$ has first row and first column all zero, so $(1,0,0)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue zero.

Comment: This is just the first example I came up with: there are bound to be many more of this sort. In the $2\times2$ case one can check there are no such examples.

Comment: Is there some simple intuition behind this example? In my example the point is to set up $AB$ and $BA$ to send a given vector to another given vector without fixing an invariant subspace for either (so that no eigenvectors are determined by my setup). You seem to have done something slightly different.

Comment: @Ian I calculated $\det{[A,B]}$ for diagonal $A$ and a general $B$ to find out what the condition for having a zero eigenvalue was. It turned out it could be factored to $(d_1-d_2)(d_2-d_3)(d_3-d_1)(b_{12}b_{23}b_{31}-b_{13}b_{32}b_{21})$. So we can force a zero eigenvalue by setting two diagonal elements equal, and then any $B$ with no eigenvectors in the eigenspace of the multiple eigenvalue of $A$ will work.

Answer (score 3):

Take $A,B$ to be $4 \times 4$ matrices such that the first column of $A$ is $e_2$, the last column of $A$ is $e_3$, the second column of $B$ is $e_3$, and the first column of $B$ is $e_4$. Then

$$(AB-BA)e_1=ABe_1-BAe_1=Ae_4-Be_2=e_3-e_3=0.$$

(The point of the choices was to create two "parallel paths" from $1$ to $3$, namely $1 \to 4 \to 3$ and $1 \to 2 \to 3$.)

Notice though that the choices we made here did not create an invariant subspace yet: $A$ sends the span of $\{ e_1,e_4 \}$ to the span of $\{ e_2,e_3 \}$ and $B$ sends the span of $\{ e_1,e_2 \}$ to the span of $\{ e_3,e_4 \}$. So these choices do not uniquely specify *any* eigenvectors of either matrix. Thus taking the other two unspecified columns of $A$ and those of $B$ at random will typically give all different eigenvectors.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another counterexample. Let $n>2$, the underlying field is real and

- $A=\operatorname{diag}(n,\,n-1,\,\ldots,\,1)$,
- $T$ be the skew-symmetric Toeplitz matrix whose first row is $(0,\,1,\,\frac12,\,\ldots,\,\frac1{n-1})$,
- $C$ be any skew-symmetric matrix with a nonzero off-diagonal entry on every column when $n$ is odd, or any *hollow, singular* symmetric matrix with a nonzero off-diagonal entry on every column when $n$ is even. E.g. when $n$ is even, one may take $C=\pmatrix{S&S\\ S&S}$ where $S$ is any hollow symmetric matrix with a nonzero off-diagonal entry on every column,
- $B=T\circ C$, the Hadamard product of $T$ and $C$.

Note that $C$ is singular and $B$ is is symmetric when $n$ is odd or skew-symmetric when $n$ is even. Moreover, $(AB-BA)_{ij}=(a_i-a_j)t_{ij}c_{ij}=c_{ij}$. Hence $A,B$ are diagonalisable and $AB-BA=C$ is singular. However, by construction, every column of $B$ possesses a nonzero off-diagonal entry. Hence $A$ and $B$ do not share any eigenvector.